# Getting 503 error from Karate for API which works fine on Postman or Insomnia

Tags: karate

We are seeing a very wierd Karate related issue in our office. We had bunch of apis and urls which were workign fine till few months back for 20-30 of us using Karate.

all of a sudden sometime in last few months most of the folks in my team are getting 503 error for same apis using Karate only.  But same apis are working fine with exact same request through postman or insomnia or other tools.

all apis work fine for me and every 1 has same setup as me as i have only given setup steps to everyone else. But same apis dont work for others in my team.

We checked for proxy issiue but that does not seem to be an issue.

We are using below karate configuration

```
compile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-core:0.9.6.RC3'
compile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.6.RC3'
compile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-testng:0.8.0.RC9'
compile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:0.9.6.RC2'
compile 'net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting:4.8.0'
```

Can someone point to what might be the root cause?

Comment: most certainly a proxy issue, see the comments on these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+postman+proxy (and by the way I don't recommend mixing library versions like you are doing, and we don't support old versions)

Comment: The root cause was older java version . We were using java version 1.8_241 . Ocne we upgraded to 1.8_272 this issue got automatically resolved.